# Remove everything but alphabets from an String

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, linq

I wanna remove any chars but Alphabets from a given string in an **efficient** way. Any suggestion?

Comment: What exactly is an 'Alphabet'? Do you mean English alphabet characters only, or perhaps also characters like šľď, or maybe even Asian characters?

Comment: What do you mean by alphabets? The English alphabet letters? Or also Swedish, Greek and Russian? Would you consider Chinese characters alphabet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var result = str.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c));
```

I was quite intrigued by @KirillPolishchuk's answer so I've just made a small benchmark with LINQPad using a randomly built string, here's the full code (I had to slightly change my original code though as it returned an IEnumerable):

```
void Main()
{
    TimeSpan elapsed;
    string result;

    elapsed = TheLINQWay(buildString(1000000), out result);
    Console.WriteLine("LINQ way: {0}", elapsed);

    elapsed = TheRegExWay(buildString(1000000), out result);
    Console.WriteLine("RegEx way: {0}", elapsed);
}

TimeSpan TheRegExWay(string s, out string result)
{
    Stopwatch stopw = new Stopwatch();

    stopw.Start();
    result = Regex.Replace(s, @"\P{L}", string.Empty);
    stopw.Stop();

    return stopw.Elapsed;
}

TimeSpan TheLINQWay(string s, out string result)
{
    Stopwatch stopw = new Stopwatch();

    stopw.Start();
    result = new string(s.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray());
    stopw.Stop();

    return stopw.Elapsed;
}

string buildString(int len)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
    Random r = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        buffer[i] = (byte)r.Next(256);

    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
}
```

And here's the result:

```
LINQ way: 00:00:00.0150030
RegEx way: 00:00:00.2788130
```

One word still needs to be said though: as Servy pointed out in his comment, the regex is faster with shorter strings.

Comment: You may want to check the LINQ method as the result does not return what you think it does.  I.e it appears to return an empty string every time.  This would certainly skew the result.

Comment: Note that the Regex could be compiled, so if it's run on a lot of small strings rather than just one large string (or even several large strings) it's relative performance might improve.  Your LINQ method also concats each char using string concatenation.  Why not just use `new string(linqquery.ToArray())` or a stringbuilder?  Finally, your LINQ query is never actually enumerated, it's just built, which is why your test here has it so much quicker.  It's not actually generating any output.

Comment: @Servy thanks for the comment, I really could not understand how the LINQ query could have been faster than the implementation in my answer (tested that, too). Now I see...

Comment: @Servy You are right, I have fixed it all. Thanks for pointing it out :) And the regex with shorter string is really faster ;)

Comment: @WarrenRox: You are right, I have fixed it all. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\P{L}", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way I could think of:

```
string input = "ABCD 13 ~";

// at worst, all characters are alphabetical, so we have to accommodate for that
char[] output = new char[input.Length];

int numberOfAlphabeticals = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    char character = input[i];
    var charCode = (byte) character;

    // based on ASCII 
    if ((charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90) || (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122))
    {
        output[numberOfAlphabeticals ] = character;
        ++numberOfAlphabeticals ;
    }
}

string outputAsString = new string(output, 0, numberOfAlphabeticals );
```

Comment: what happens if the user inputs `"asd013 bsc ^&"`?

Comment: @Lirik The program returns `"asdbsc"`.

Comment: I guess `output` is initialized to `0` by default so `new string` skips the `null`s.

Comment: @Lirik could you please be more specific? I don't really understand what you mean by "skipping `null`s".

Comment: nevermind... ignore my previous comment, I just realized that you're using the `numberOfAlphabeticals` as an index to the output array and then you're constructing a string with exactly that many characters.

Comment: Actually, it is not. Now that @BlackBear fixed the LINQ query so that it produces  correct results, it is slower.

Comment: Your code can be optimized a little more, removing the variables from the loop and using only one variable is faster, see my version of your code: http://pastie.org/3679990 I also ran benchmarks on it and it's faster than the LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fastest way (performance-wise) to do this to create an array of 122 characters, convert the string of choice to a byte array and use a `StringBuilder` to build another string which has the characters removed:

```
private static char[] alphabet = {'\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',};
```

And here is the removal function (haven't compiled it, but it should give you the idea):

```
string RemoveNonAlpha(string value)
{
    byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < asciiBytes.Length; i++)
    {
        if((asciiBytes[i] >= 65 && asciiBytes[i] <= 90) || (asciiBytes[i] >= 97 && asciiBytes[i] <= 122))
        {
            sb.Append(alphabet[asciiBytes[i]]);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

### Update

Based on [Nikola's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895027/remove-everything-but-alphabets-from-an-string/9895418#9895418), here is an improved version:

```
private static string RemoveNonAlpha(string value)
{
    char[] output = new char[value.Length];
    int numAlpha = 0;
    byte charCode = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
    {
        charCode = (byte)value[i];
        if ((charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90) || (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122))
        {
            output[numAlpha] = value[i];
            numAlpha++;
        }
    }

    return new string(output, 0, numAlpha);
}
```

Here are the results compared to using LINQ:

```
The LINQ way 100: 6.7935
The fast way 100: 0.4648
The LINQ way 1000: 0.0442
The fast way 1000: 0.0134
The LINQ way 10000: 0.2078
The fast way 10000: 0.143
The LINQ way 100000: 2.0617
The fast way 100000: 1.3864
```

Comment: You seriously think this is the fastest way?  Your array is not even complete considering `A` and `a` are different values in ASCII.

Comment: Does anybody care to explain the -1?

Comment: @Ramhound both 'a' and 'A' are in the array, just scroll to the right. I would be willing to say that this will probably one of the fastest ways to do it. I haven't compiled the code, but the idea is pretty accurate.

Comment: You have basically re-implemented `Char.IsLetter()` so how is it the fastest way? On top of that, efficient can have many meanings, I surely don't think it is efficient to write out 122 characters for a single array to do something that is already implemented in the .NET framework

Comment: @Jetti it's a static array... you write it once by hand and you never have to write it again-> that's pretty fast. I'd say that's efficient too: you never have to write it again.

Comment: @Lirik except when the requirements change and now it has to handle foreign alphabets. Char.IsLetter() handles unicode and languages other than English. Yes the OP specifically stated that it only needed to accept English, a better overall answer is one that can be reused. On top of that, like I stated before, your answer doesn't do anything that Char.IsLetter() doesn't and I would trust Microsoft to come up with the most efficient way to see if the character is question is a letter or not.

Comment: @Jetti There are different tools for different purposes, so if the requirements change you have to change the tools. It really depends on what's your performance requirement: if you want something that's going to work for every case, then you can expect that the performance will be slower. If you want to make something work for a very specific case, then you can optimize the code and maximize the performance.

Comment: @Lirik - so I used the same method that BlackBear did and my results show [this](http://imgur.com/8uodJ). Your method is faster than RegEx and even faster than using Char.IsLetter() (so I was wrong) but it is still slower than using LINQ (which [BlackBear](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9895049/509746) suggested). I must admit this way was faster than I thought it would be.

Comment: @Jetti Turns out we're both wrong: Nikola Anusev's is the fastest (with a couple of minor modifications from me), which is more along the lines of what I was going for. See my benchmark results and my code here: http://pastie.org/3679927

Answer (score 0):

use

^\w

as input in the replace method of regex

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx